# Using scope prototype on abstract component with anonymous implementations

Tags: java, spring

I have the following scenario:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public abstract class AbstractA {
    protected abstract String getData();
}
```

Now I will require to create instances of this class in a dynamic manner (using anonymous inner classes). Such as:

```
@Component
public class B {
    public void some_method() {
        //Obviously this is wrong, I want to be able to do this through Spring/beans.
        new AbstractA() {
            protected abstract String getData() {
                return "abc";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I be able to get instrances of the prototype bean in such scenario?

Comment: I think trying to do this defeats the point of using Spring.

Comment: Use a configuration, look up @Configuration